# Check if value in CSV in specific colum is empty

Tags: powershell, csv

I have one CSV file with 3 columns (Header1, Header2, Header3) and I need to check if value for each row in column 2 (header2) is empty, if yes then value from Column 3 (Header 3) need to be copy to column 2 in same row. I hope it is clear.

Input Data

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,
ABC,123,123,
AXY,,456,
XYZ,,152,
ASD,528,,
```

Output

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,
ABC,123,123,
AXY,456,456,
XYZ,152,152,
ASD,528,,
```

I tired below code but it is not working

```
$csvFile1 = Import-Csv -Path "D:\AA_servers.txt" -Delimiter ","
$ht = @{}
foreach ($item in $csvFile1) {
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($item.Header2)) {
        $ht[$item.Header2] = $line.Header3
    }
} 
$csvFile1 | Export-Csv -Path "D:\AA_servers.txt" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Thank you for support.

Comment: Change `$ht[$item.Header2] = $line.Header3` to `$item.Header2 = $item.Header3`

Comment: I tried that also `$item.Header2 = $item.Header3` and it is not working :(

Comment: Why are you exporting the CSV with `;` instead if `,` as in the import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the purpose of the $ht variable is.
But dumping that makes the code work.

Proof of Concept:

```
$csv = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Header1,Header2,Header3
ABC,123,124
AXY,,456
XYZ,,152
ASD,528,
'@

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($row.Header2)) {
        $row.Header2 = $row.Header3
    }
} 
$csv
```

Output:

```
Header1 Header2 Header3
------- ------- -------
ABC     123     124
AXY     456     456
XYZ     15      15
ASD     528
```

For real usage:
(Just change the path.)

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\AA_servers.txt'

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($row.Header2)) {
        $row.Header2 = $row.Header3
    }
}

$csv | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\AA_servers.txt' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: But input data is always diffrent and data is changing so i can' t do it that in your way

Comment: I can't put data here as its od sensitive company data. CSV file is creating every day and once csv file was updated then my script will be executed, it is not live data file. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Replace the `ConvertFrom-Csv` here document to the `Import-Csv` from a file that you were using.

Comment: Not really,  as on your code you always import same data and i have diffrent data every day, can you put code again please

Comment: Filename is same every day, so you mean Luke that ' $csv = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\AA_servers.txt' foreach ($row in $csv) { if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($row.Header2)) { $row.Header2 = $row.Header3 } }  $csv | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\AA_servers.txt' -NoTypeInformation

Comment: Then there shouldn't be any issue with the script. Remove the # signs, remove the static definition of $csv used only for Proof of Concept, change the path to whatever you need, and run it once a day :)

Comment: @majan As long as the **headers** do not change, _" i have diffrent data every day"_ doesn't matter. Or do you mean that these headers also change every day?

Comment: Code is working